# Customize My Account Customer navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account

I was trying to screenshot like HTML

[image: My Account navigation] 
My questions

1) Can i achieve by Native magento navigation (like can i make acccordian like structure using XML where links are picked) 
2) When i tried to replace with it with custom HTML all by links are replaced with current page link , like i am on Wishlist page all the other links will be also be wishlist URLS , How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change default customer navigation this way:

copy

`app\design\frontend\base\default\template\customer\account\navigation.phtml`

to your custom theme

`app\design\frontend\{your_package_name}\{your_theme_name}\customer\account\navigation.phtml`

and edit html structure inside copied file.

All available links you can get from `$_links` array

Comment: Yes i did that But all the custom links apply is replaced by current page Url as i mentioned

Comment: Could you please post your navigation.phtml here. I guess there are some problems with data processing